# Power Pivot Sort By Column Not Working in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, powerpivot

I'm trying to sort a Month value (e.g. Dec-16) in a date dimension using a Month Sort column. I can set the sort by column in the data model no problem but when I use the Month value in a pivot table it is sorting alphabetically

- The month sort column is of data type & format a whole number
- The date dimension is set as a date table
- The cardinality between month value & month sort is 1:1
- I have refreshed the model & pivot table
- I have fiddled around with the sorting of Month Value (A>Z,Z>A etc.)
- I'm using the latest build of Excel 2016 (7571.2072)

I've done this hundreds of times in SSAS Tabular & Power BI but not recently in PowerPivot.  What could I be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I couldn't find any direct solution for it, so I just added another column to the sorting table with the numbers from 1-12 and then sorted the Pivot table by that numbers A>Z. My sorting table was a linked table to a support sheet in the workbook. If you found any other solution, please let me know.